# A xib file is added when i add new Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, xcode

When i try to add new `Localizable.strings` file to my project (for French, German and so other languages), i noticed that a xib file is added for each `Localizable.strings` file. Means for `Localizable.strings (French)`, i got `ViewController.xib (French)`. 
How can i get rid of that?

Comment: does your original ViewControl.xib file have language support selected for french

Comment: from the right panel in xcode select the first tab. There is a localization option, see if it has any entries for french . http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/infopane.jpg check for your xib file

Comment: posting as an answer so you can vote up n accept =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the right panel in xcode select the first tab. There is a localization option, see if it has any entries for french.

http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/infopane.jpg check for your xib file